# Build ASP.NET Web Site App_Licenses.dll on command line

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild

Our ASP.NET web *site* projects are built and published automatically by Jenkins - but no App_Licenses.dll file is generated from the licenses.licx file.

On my dev build this file is generated fine - is there any way I can find out what command line Visual Studio is using to build the file so I can add this to the build process?

Or does anyone know how to configure the right target for MSBuild to generate this file as part of the build?